# Cheerio returning undefined for class with hyphons and '/'

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I am using cheerio to scrape checkpoints. I want to get the 'checkpoint message' and 'timestamp' from the div. My aim is to get the message and timestamp within each parent div..

This is returning undefined : `$('.roster__item.roster__item--flex.5\\/12.palm-1\\/1')`. What am I doing wrong? I understand that I needed to escape the hyphen and forward slash but I'm out of options.

https://www.tnt.fr/public/suivi_colis/recherche/visubontransport.do?bonTransport=9320002023749749&radiochoixrecherche=BT&radiochoixtypeexpedition=NAT

HTML from API response: https://justpaste.it/35o9l

My Code:

```
const req = require('rfr')
// const settings = req('/settings')

// libs
const select = req('/utils/common').select

// dependencies
const request = require('request')
const async = require('async')
const moment = require('moment')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

function callApi (tracking, callback) {
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: `https://www.tnt.fr/public/suivi_colis/recherche/visubontransport.do?bonTransport=${tracking}&radiochoixrecherche=BT&radiochoixtypeexpedition=NAT`
  }

  request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
    // console.log(body)
    if (error) return callback(error)
    else return callback(null, body)
  })
}

function refresh (tracking, callback) {
  const tno = tracking[0].tracking_number
  async.waterfall([
    // interact with API
    function get (waterfallCallback) {
      callApi(tracking, function (err, html) {
        if (err) return waterfallCallback(err)
        return waterfallCallback(null, cheerio.load(html))
      })
    },

    function transformHtml (html, waterfallCallback) {
      var $ = html
      var checkpoints = []

      // console.log(body)

      console.log('=======================')
      console.log($('.roster__item.roster__item--flex.5\\/12.palm-1\\/1').html())
      console.log('=======================')

      const update = {
        tracking_update: {
          tracking_number: tno,
          slug: 'tnt',
          checkpoints
        }
      }
    }], function waterfallDone (err, updates) {
    callback(err, updates)
  })
}
```

**These are the checkpoints from the HTML:**

```
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-even" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Colis livr&#233;</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">02/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 12:08</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1"></div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-odd" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">D&#233;part en livraison</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">02/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 08:06</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1">TREMBLAY</div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-even" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Arriv&#233;e &#224; l&#39;agence de destination</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">02/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 06:09</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1">TREMBLAY</div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-odd" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Colis pris en compte par l'agence TNT</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">01/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 21:08</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1">CAEN</div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-even" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Colis en cours d&#39;acheminement</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">01/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 20:00</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1"></div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-odd" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Colis chez l'exp&#233;diteur</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">01/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 00:00</div>
    <div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheerio should never return `undefined`. It should always return the number of elements found. I think, if it does, there's something wrong. How do you load the HTML page in Cheerio?

Comment: Updated my question. The thing is it does work if I select other classes and returns the text.

Comment: Looks good to me... I'm not surprised Cheerio has trouble selecting classes with slashes in them. I suspect the slash character to be invalid inside a class name or ID...

Comment: Just tried via cheerio playground and the selector is fine btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this and it works perfectly fine:

```
let html = `<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-even" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
<div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Colis livr&#233;</div>
<div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">02/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 12:08</div>
<div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1"></div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-odd" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
<div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">D&#233;part en livraison</div>
<div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">02/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 08:06</div>
<div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1">TREMBLAY</div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-even" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
<div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Arriv&#233;e &#224; l&#39;agence de destination</div>
<div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">02/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 06:09</div>
<div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1">TREMBLAY</div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-odd" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
<div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Colis pris en compte par l'agence TNT</div>
<div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">01/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 21:08</div>
<div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1">CAEN</div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-even" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
<div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Colis en cours d&#39;acheminement</div>
<div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">01/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 20:00</div>
<div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1"></div>
</div>
<div class="roster roster-palm 1/1 tnt-odd" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; padding-left: 28px;">
<div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 5/12 palm-1/1" style="white-space: normal">Colis chez l'exp&#233;diteur</div>
<div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 3/12 palm-1/1">01/09/2020 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 00:00</div>
<div class="roster__item roster__item--flex 4/12  palm-1/1"></div>
</div>`;

const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
let d = $(".roster__item.roster__item--flex.5\\/12.palm-1\\/1").html();
console.log(d);
// outputs: Colis livr&#xE9;
```

Comment: i also tried on https://cheerio-playground.herokuapp.com/ and it's fine as well

Comment: That's good news but this is super weird for me. If I use html() instead of text() I get null.

Comment: I updated my question to include my full code. I must be doing something wrong but the API is returning the full HTML. I can't post it in this question because it exceeds the character limit.. :/

Comment: I'll try to find out what the issue is, thanks for the entire html

Comment: For some reason, cheerio isn't returning the full HTML of this page. https://www.tnt.fr/public/suivi_colis/recherche/visubontransport.do?bonTransport=9320002023749749&radiochoixrecherche=BT&radiochoixtypeexpedition=NAT

Comment: You see the checkpoints underneath the title 'Etapes de votre expédition'. That's what I need but for some reason, this isn't being loaded.. you can ignore the justpaste.it as this won't contain the full HTML.

Comment: The html you provided me does not contain an element with the 5/12 class and the palm-1/1 class. however there is one with the 2/12 class and the palm-1/1 class. For this element this scippet works:  let d = $(".roster__item.roster__item--flex.2\\/12.palm-1\\/1").html();

Comment: 'https://www.tnt.fr/public/suivi_colis/recherche/visubontransport.do?bonTransport=9320002023749749&radiochoixrecherche=BT&radiochoixtypeexpedition=NAT', this works but when I interpolate the tracking number in the URL it only responds with part of the HTML. Have no clue why but I will mark your answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe Part of the Page HTML is dynamicly loaded during runtime by scripts. In this case cheerio doesnt get that part because it does not execute the scripts. For scraping like this, where you want the page to fully load, script execution included, you could check out puppeteer - its a headless chromium browser for node js